# do not want to open a new window in flash

Tags: flash, window, hyperlink

I have a home page in flash that links to pages in Dreamweaver. When online, I do not want a new window to open when directing to the url. (Now, I have an actionscript to go to URL, and a new window opens). Is there anyway to keep it the same?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using [`navigateToURL`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL())? Pass `_self` as the second parameter. See documentation:

> **`window:String (default = null)`** — The browser window or HTML frame in which to display the document indicated by the request parameter. You can enter the name of a specific window or use one of the following values:

```
* "_self" specifies the current frame in the current window.
* "_blank" specifies a new window.
* "_parent" specifies the parent of the current frame.
* "_top" specifies the top-level frame in the current window.
```

> If you do not specify a value for this parameter, a new empty window is created. In the stand-alone player, you can either specify a new ("_blank") window or a named window. The other values don't apply.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the link target to `_self`

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
getUrl("http://theurl.com/page.html", "_self");
```